# What are the current forerunners for enterprise social networks?

Tags: social-networking, enterprise

I'm looking for an actively developed and high quality social networking application targeted at the enterprise i.e. running on a corporate network. What are the pros and cons of it? Also, is it free or licensed?

Answer (score 1):

There has a open source enterprise social network: [Teampopor](http://code.google.com/p/teampopor/). Just check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is sure making a run at this space with **SharePoint and Outlook.**

You can find plenty about those tools by Googling, but [here's one article about Sharepoint that has some screenshots](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/enterprise-20/5-ways-social-networking-has-improved-in-sharepoint-2010-007325.php).

And here's an article about the [Outlook Social Connector.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/outlook/archive/2009/11/18/announcing-the-outlook-social-connector.aspx)

However dubious you might think these tools are, remember that citizens of the corporate world are largely blocked from using other social networking tools at work, such as Facebook and LinkedIn, or even Hotmail, gMail and the like. So any tool at all might be better than no tool.

And no, these are not free tools.

Comment: I was looking for reviews of things like http://www.novell.com/products/vibe-cloud/